# Calculate list of percentage to get a final percentage

Tags: python

I have some trouble to calcul a list of percentage to a final percentage

my actual code is

```
bonus = [120, 11, 23, 92]
```

everything in this list is already a percentage.

and I want a try to make a function that calcul all this percentage to have a final one, like

```
120% + 11% + 23% + 92% = X%
```

Comment: How about a one-liner? `print(f"{sum(bonus)/100:.2%}")`

Comment: What is final percentage? Is next value is percentage of previous percentage or you just need  to sum this value and then use sum as a percentage?

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76862089/edit) your question to include what you have tried so far to solve the issue? See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, what is the expected output of your posted example?

Comment: It is not clear from the question how you intend to combine percentages. Once you decide that, the rest is easy. If you just want the sum as the question seems to indicate, then just use the python builtin sum. If you want to multiply then be sure to correct them to the correct form (divide by 100). If you don't know what you want, we don't either -- it's a math question without context. Did it maybe come with some text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `sum()` function.

In your case:

```
bonus = [120, 11, 23, 92]

final = sum(bonus)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Pythoncraft stated above: Try the **sum()** function

However if you wish to convert each element into a percent before applying the **sum()** function:

Use List Comprehension.

syntax:

```
new_list = [new_item for item in old_list]
```

In your case:

```
new_list = [item/100 for item in bonus]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
new_list = []
for item in bonus:
  percent = item/100
  new_list.apend(percent)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the final percentage by the following code :

```
bonus = [120, 11, 23, 92]

listSum = str(sum(bonus))+"%"
```